# Flash crashes and reboots computer

Tags: flash

.
Hi! and thanks for your help in advance. Recently I bought a laptop with an A8-6410B. I installed  ubuntu 14.10 without issues but when using sites like youtube, the computer crashes and reboots by itself.

I suspect is the flash puglin, because every time, seconds before the computer rebooting, the video stops, makes a weird sound repeating the last sound (like a scratch disk) and then reboots. I installed diferent flash plugins but no solution in that. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score -2):

try removing flash and re-install in some occasions, it has worked for me, with ubuntu 10.04 and ubuntu 14.04